# How do I prompt an alert before exiting a View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a pop up prompt but I'm doing something wrong. I have a button that I should change View Controllers when pressed, sort of like the back button on a Navigation Bar but without the Navigation Bar. I want the Alert Pop up to confirm "Yes or No" before actually leaving the view. Currently with my code it just transitions back to the View Controller I link it to without without the prompt. Any ideas?

```
@IBAction func exit(sender: AnyObject) {


var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wait", message: "Are you sure you want to exit?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize `viewdidload` method first

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var myBackButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    myBackButton.addTarget(self, action: "goback:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    myBackButton.setTitle("YOUR TITLE", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myBackButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myBackButton.sizeToFit()
    var myCustomBackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBackButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem
}
```

Then `implement` custom `back button action`

```
func goback(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
       var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: “Wait”, message: "Are you sure you want to exit?
", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “YES”, style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      println("Handle YES logic here")
      self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

      }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “NO”, style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      println("Handle NO Logic here")
      }))

}
```